# How to access data from an external spreadsheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a spreadsheet with some data tables that I want to use in other spreadsheets script. How can I call this spreadsheet by its ID and access the data?\

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced), I know that custom functions are not allowed to access other spreadsheets, a solution would be to put this function in a menu and run it, since it'd ask for the user's authorization. But this is not an option because I am using the data with the built-in method `onEdit()`.\

Also, I tried accessing the spreadsheet via `onOpen()` since it's not a custom function but still no success. Any other solution?

My code:

```js
function onOpen(){
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  src = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");
```

Error message:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

And `appscript.json`

```json
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]
}
```

Lastly, I also tried creating an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) with this code:

```js
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
```

But the trigger does not seem to be called upon opening the sheet.

Comment: Could you limit your question to 1 question: preferably only the last part starting from "Lastly, I also tried cr...". What makes you think the trigger didn't work?

Comment: @TheMaster it is one question after all. I just presented my attempts. And I don't know why it didn't work. I tried to create a trigger manually from the triggers page in the dashboard using the `myFunction` and it seems to work

Comment: So problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

### As you already realized, custom functions and simple trigger cannot perform requests that require authorization

- `SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");` is one of those requests
- You are on the right track with the installable triggers - they can trigger the execution of requests that require authorization
- I think your problem is the correct implementation of installable triggers
- `function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger` creates an installable `onOpen` trigger that calls the function `myFunction` when the sheet is open

- This means that you need to create the function `myFunction` first

- Also, you need to run `function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger()`  once manually - to install the trigger

Sample complete code:

```js
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}


function myFunction(){
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  src = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");
  Logger.log(src.getActiveSheet().getName());
}
```

**Note:**

Instead of implementing the function `createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger()`, you can install the trigger manually by going on `Edit->My project's triggers` and bind a trigger of the desired type to the desired function, see also [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Comment: The last point is what I was missing. I didn't realize I had to run the function manually at first to actually implement the trigger. Also, it's a good suggestion to implement it directly in the project's trigger so I don't have to run the function manually! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

First, in the line  src = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID"); did you replace the id with the actual spreadsheet ID?
That's the number at the end of the url. I assume you did, but it doesn't show that you did in your example.

Second, just for testing, try to do this action in a regular function (not a trigger) to get things to work. Have you done that? Then you can focus on the spreadsheet access without worrying if the trigger is causing a problem.

Comment: Yes I did replace the ID, just suppressed in the post and forgot to mention. Well I did tried in a function without the trigger, but custom functions don't have access to `openById` method

Comment: when they say 'custom functions' I think they mean something called in a formula in a cell on the sheet, not a trigger or something you write yourself. I don't think the 'custom function' thing is what you mean. I use triggers to open/reference other spreadsheets all the time.

Comment: are you expecting the spreadsheet to actually open? if so, that's different. to do that, you need to open a browser window. That's javascript and html to create a popup. 'openbyid' gives you access to the spreadsheet but it doesn't open a new browser window with that sheet.

Comment: No, I know it doesn't open the spreadsheet with UI. I just need to read it and get the data to use in the current spreadsheet running the script. But the `openbyId` is not accessible by custom functions. See the reference I linked

Comment: why don't you just importrange into a hidden sheet? do you know how to do that?

Comment: As a matter of fact I do not. However, I'm not sure it would fit my needs. Importing the range would make the data only be available to that spreadsheet and I need the source tables to be centralized so when other teams make changes, they are reflected to my other sheets using it.

Comment: it sounds like you have a database design question not a specific coding question. your answer likely considers remote updates (openById) and importrange and maybe Forms as well. Also consider the new Google Tables.